# MSBuild from command line errors - Reference required to System.Xml

Tags: msbuild

I'm creating a batch script which will get latest version of the code of an application, then build it using msbuild. Everything works until the msbuild part. Here's the line that runs msbuild:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe "code/Solution.sln" /p:Configuration="Debug"
```

And the thing errors all over the place - all the errors say something like:

```
C:\code\project1\codefile1.vb(882): error BC30009: Reference required to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' containing the implemented interface 'System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable'. Add one to your project.
```

Everything builds without errors from from Visual Studio 2008. What's going on here?

Comment: Without knowing more about your solution it's hard to say.  What's the *first* error it throws?

Comment: it's the first error, the last error, and every error in between. Reference required to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0 ...'

Comment: Do you run the script on the same computer that build correctly with VS? Do you have a System.Xml dependency in your vbproj file?

Comment: It builds fine on the same machine in Visual Studio. I did notice that there is nothing that references System.Xml in the vbproj file.

Comment: maybe you can explicitly specify a target for msbuild in the batch file?  also, there's a way to get msbuild to be verbose: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/29/475157.aspx . With that, you may be able to gain some insight into what msbuild is doing vs what you expect it to be doing.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably most detailed descriptions on what is going wrong:

[MSBuild Can't Find Secondary References](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b2801834-0ee6-4079-aa18-392cd3a8fe8b/msbuild-cant-find-project-references?forum=msbuild)

[Resolving Binary References in MSBuild](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Resolving-Binary-References-in-MSBuild.aspx)

In short:
Your project references assembly X.
X contains a class, that implements interface from assembly Y.
Your project does not reference Y, so MSBuild fails.
Studio acts a bit smarter and finds the second level reference.

Comment: Good answer. When I build in Debug configuration VS builds fine, but when I build in Release configuration I get the errors.

Answer (score 2):

Do just what it says and add a reference to System.Xml to your project.

Project->Add Reference